# Is this proof of positive definiteness correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

$A$ is a positive definite real matrix of order $n$. I have to prove that $A$ is p.d. iff its symmetric part $T=\frac{(A+A^T)}{2}$ is p.d.

Proof: $T$ is positive definite
$\iff \langle Tv,v \rangle > 0$ for all non-zero $v$
$\iff \frac{1}{2} \langle (A+A^T)v,v \rangle > 0$ which is true.
Because when $A$ is positive definite so is $A^T$ and hence $\langle A^Tv,v \rangle > 0$
Thus, proved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that $\langle Av,v\rangle>0$, for every $v\ne0$, then you also have $\langle A^Tv,v\rangle>0$. Therefore also
$$
\Bigl\langle\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)v,v\Bigr\rangle>0
$$
So one direction is proved, namely “if $A$ is positive definite, then $T$ is positive definite”.

Now suppose that $T$ is positive definite and consider $U=A-T$, which is antisymmetric. If $v\ne0$, you want to prove that
$$
0<\langle Av,v\rangle=\langle Tv,v\rangle+\langle Uv,v\rangle
$$
Now you can note that
$$\langle Uv,v\rangle=v^TUv=v^T(-U^T)v=-v^TU^Tv=-\langle v,Uv\rangle=-\langle Uv,v\rangle$$
and therefore $\langle Uv,v\rangle=0$.

---

Your attempt is invalid, because you're assuming what you want to prove.

Comment: This is great. Thanks.

Comment: What would change if $A$ were a complex matrix and the transpose was replaced by the conjugate transpose?

Comment: @user733666 It would no longer be true.

Comment: $A$ is positive definite implies that its conjugate transpose would also be positive definite in that case. So the first part remains the same.

Comment: @user733666 The second part would not work.

Comment: This says that it would be true though, so I’m confused because I thought it wouldn’t. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PositiveDefiniteMatrix.html

Comment: @user733666 I stand corrected!

Comment: So now, I am able to prove that $A$ being positive definite also implies that $A^H$ is positive definite hence the first part of your proof follows. So, would the second part also follow? $U$ would then be...anti-Hermitian?

Answer (score 1):

You've proven that if $A$ is positive definite, then so is $T.$ You have not proven that if $T$ is positive definite then so is $A.$

Comment: I thought since ‘$\iff$’ is used, it works. Can you show a hint for the other part?

Comment: Or if there’s a simpler way.

Comment: You used iff twice, but then you didn't use iff for the very last line, where you start by saying "Because when $A$ is positive definite," assuming $A$ is positive definite.

Comment: Oh, my bad — A is given to be positive definite in the problem. I’ll change it. Then the proof works?

Comment: @user733666 Are you sure? What would be the point of making an if and only if statement about $A$ being positive definite if you were allowed to assume that $A$ was positive definite?

Comment: Yes I just checked again. It seems to me that ‘$A$ is positive definite iff $T$ is positive definite’ is what has been asked to prove.

Comment: Anyhow, I would like to know how to proceed if it weren’t given that $A$ is positive definite. Can you help me a bit with that?